# Pipe value to exit code

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I'm looking to create a one-line command which does some stuff and gets a value (which would generally be output) and instead turn that into an exit code (so I can trigger a subsequent step which responds to non-zero exit codes).

For example, running something like this:

```
echo 5 | exit
```

And then having a subsequent `echo $?` output `5`, the value I gave it earlier.

The above syntax doesn't work. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Generally, speaking, I would tend to describe this as something of an antipattern -- it's incurring performance overhead; there's probably a better way to accomplish your actual goal which won't. Unfortunately, without seeing that actual goal, we can't provide much intelligent advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming:

```
cmd() { echo 5; }
```

For a literal answer:

```
cmd | (read -r rc && exit "$rc")
```

However, you can also run:

```
( exit "$(cmd)" ) # parens create a subshell so we aren't exiting the main shell
```

Comment: This seems to do the trick. I was able to do it directly with `( exit \`echo 5\` )` which works as well. Thanks.

Comment: `(exit "$(echo 5)")` is actually the preferred modern notation -- backticks are hard to nest (which is to say, `foo "$(bar "$(baz)")"` is *far* easier to write than the backtick equivalent), and `$()` has been supported ever since the 1991 publication of the POSIX sh standard.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use command substitution:

```
( exit $(cmd) )
```

Assuming `cmd` is returning an integer between `0-255`

An example:

```
$> ( exit $(echo 5) )
$> echo $?

5
```